# Исключения в php

Tags: php

**Есть такой код:**

```
<?php
class customException extends Exception{}
$a;
try{
if(!isset($a)){
    $thrower = new customException("Variable not initialize");
    throw $thrower;
}
echo $a."\n";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
var_dump($thrower instanceof Exception);
?>
```

И он будет работать! Только я не понимаю почему?! Ведь мы "выбросили" исключение на класс `customException`, почему тогда он совместим с классом `Exception`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что все исключения наследуются от базового класса `Exception`. Поэтому указав `Exception` в блоке `catch` вы получаете возможность перехвата всех его наследников.

В PHP 7 обычные ошибки тоже рассматриваются как исключения и их можно перехватывать при помощи `try ... catch` (не все правда, деление на ноль например, сделано не перехватываемым). Ошибки наследуются от нового базового класса `Error`, поэтому при `Exception` и его наследники их не отловливают.

Comment: то есть это является языковой условностью, что мы можем "ловить" родителя, а "выбрасывать" потомка?
И в чем тогда различие между классом Exception и Error, насколько я знаю есть класс ErrorException (но правда он наследуется от Exception)

Comment: @MaximPro Долгое время в PHP ошибки, предупреждения и замечания выдавались в стандартный поток ошибок. Их отображение регулировалось на уровне директив php.ini. С PHP 7 решили ошибки оформить в виде исключений, но чтобы не поломать обратную совместимость дерево наследования ошибок сделали полностью независимым от Exception-дерева, в том числе и от ErrorException. Этот процесс связан с тем, что изначально PHP был разработан как не объектно-ориентированный язык, и объектно-ориентированные возможности в него внедряют до сих пор.

Comment: я знаю что php изначально был только процедурным языком программирования, соответсвенно "фич" ооп не было.

Comment: @MaximPro, я лишь к тому, что эти два типа исключений решили сделать независимыми. Вы в своем коде тоже можете сделать независимые исключения, если будете отлавливать потомков, а не базовый класс.

Comment: и также могу создать свой класс имплементируя интерфейс Throwable
p.s А как сделать так как вы сказали?

Comment: @MaximPro унаследуйте от customException два исключения firstException и secondException. Если в catch поместить secondException, то firstException не будут перехватываться, не будут перехватыватся и Exception c customException. Да, можно попробовать реализовать Throwable, но сам я не пробовал - не берусь судить получится ли.

Comment: Хмм интересно...спасибо за ответ и обсуждение